# ListView smoothScrollBy, first click ignored, issue in Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, expandablelistview, smooth-scrolling, expandablelistadapter

I am working with this library, http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/slide-expandable-listview/. I am trying the sample code. The thing is, when you click an element and the expanded view it's out of the screen, the adapter makes it scroll like this:

```
final int movement = target.getBottom();
listView.smoothScrollBy(movement, getAnimationDuration());
```

It almost works but there is an issue, after scroll, first click is ignored (you need to click twice). Here is an screenshot when the list scrolls:

[image: 1]

As you can see, there is something strange, the white part at the end of the list, it shouldn't be here. After it, I click the element 4 and instead of clicking it deletes this white part:

[image: 2]

And the second click works as expected:

[image: 3]

Any idea of what can be the solution?

Thank you in advance.